# Python matching strings

Tags: python

So basically I want a program that will only work if the user types something like "I am sick" or "I am too cool" but will not work if they make a typo like "pi am cool".

Here's what I have so far:

```
text = input("text here: ") 
if re.search("i am", text) is not None:
   print("correct")
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

While you still haven't asked an actual *question*, it seems to me like you want something along the lines of

```
if text.lower().startswith('i am'):
    print('correct')
```

Or if you want to test if `'i am'` appears anywhere in the string and not just at the start, you can use `in`:

```
if 'i am' in text.lower():
    print('correct')
```

Regular expressions seem like overkill here (unless you want more flexibility than what you describe).